# Calculate Frequency of item in list

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna calculate frequency of accidents in every region, in every year. 
How can I do that using Python.

file.csv

```
Region,Year
1,2003
1,2003
2,2008
2,2007
2,2007
3,2004
1,2004
1,2004
1,2004
```

I tried using Counter, but it works only with one columns. 
Example: 
In region 1, year 2003 , there are 2 
So results should be:

```
 Region,Year, freq
    1,2003,2
    1,2003,2
    2,2008,1
    2,2007,2
    2,2007,2
    3,2004,1
    1,2004,3
    1,2004,3
    1,2004,3
```

I tried doing it this way. But it doesn't seem to be the right way.

```
from collections import Counter

data = pandas.DataFrame("file.csv")
freq_year= Counter(data.year.values)
dz = [dom[x] for x in data.year.values]
data["freq"] = data["year"].apply(lambda x: dom[x])
```

I am thinking of using Groupby. Do you know any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way, but I first append a dummy column and calculate the `freq` based on the column, like:

```
df["freq"] = 1
df["freq"] = df.groupby(["Year", "Region"]).transform(lambda x: x.sum())
```

This returns the following df:

```
  Region  Year  freq
0       1  2003     2
1       1  2003     2
2       2  2008     1
3       2  2007     2
4       2  2007     2
5       3  2004     1
6       1  2004     3
7       1  2004     3
8       1  2004     3
```

Comment: I am trying to plot this dataset. but seems that I am facing a prob. Can you check out plz this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024439/how-to-customize-axes-in-3d-hist-python-matplotlib

Comment: I don't know much about matplotlib and have no experience in 3D plot. Hope you would get help there...

Comment: Instead of adding a dummy column and summing it, you could simply choose one and use `len` (in recent `pandas`, anyway):  `df.groupby(["Year", "Region"])["Year"].transform(len)`

Answer (score 1):

Not a `pandas` solution, but gets the job done:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

inputs = []
with open('input.csv') as csvfile:
   reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
   for row in reader:
       inputs.append(tuple(row))

freqs = Counter(inputs[1:])
print freqs 
# Counter({('1', '2004'): 3, ('1', '2003'): 2, ('2', '2007'): 2, ('2', '2008'): 1, ('3', '2004'): 1})
```

The key here is to have the values as tuples so that `Counter` will find them equal.